# Predicates in nested list kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, predicate

I have a JSON list, in which I need to filter the data based on some filters.
I was using predicate for filtering, but as per my need I need to filter the nested list, and if here I use predicates I am left with 3 test predicate that's `Any, None, and All` but as I want only matched data and which I am not getting using any of these predicates.

As `Any` returns true if at least there is one match element, and `All` returns true if there are all matched elements but how can I get only the matched elements from the nested list irrespective of any non-matched element.

I can use the traditional approach of looping through the list, but I wanted to know whether it is possible to use a predicate.

Here's the sample JSON
I am trying to get the center whose session elements contains `min_age_limit is > 18` and `available_dose_1 > 0`.

```
{
"centers": [
    {
        ....
        "sessions": [
            {
                "session_id":"adad",
                ...
                "min_age_limit":45,
                "available_capacity_dose1": 5,
                "available_capacity_dose2": 5
                ...
            },
            {
                "session_id":"adad1",
                ...
                "min_age_limit":18,
                "available_capacity_dose1": 0,
                "available_capacity_dose2": 5
                ...
            },
            {
                "session_id":"adad2",
                ...
                "min_age_limit":18,
                "available_capacity_dose1": 5,
                "available_capacity_dose2": 0
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
    ....
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to use predicates.
I transformed the list to a map and then added the filters.

```
val allValidSessions = it?.data?.centers?.sortedBy { it.name }?.map { center ->
                center to center.sessions?.filter { session -> isValidSession(session, 18, selectedDose) }
            }?.toMap()

private fun isValidSession(session: Session, s: String, selectedDose: String): Boolean {
        if (session.minAgeLimit!! == s.toInt() && (if (selectedDose == "1") session.availableCapacityDose1!! > 0 else session.availableCapacityDose2!! > 0)) return true
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use *filter* for this like the following.

```
filteredList = sessions.filter{ it.min_age_limit > 18 && it.available_dose_1 > 0 }
```

To clarify, Kotlin gives support for any, none, and all for a bonus predicate. But the filter is also there. and that's what you are looking for I think.

Comment: Thanks for your response but the JSON contains sessions for every center in that case so do I need to loop through the center first and add a filter to the session?.
Please correct me. 


`centers?.forEach { center ->
                center.sessions?.filter { session ->
                    session.minAgeLimit > 18 && session.availableCapacityDose1 > 0
                }
 }`